# does Prism support compiled binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

It's not clear to me if Compiled binding is supported in prism. Its an extremely good feature that avoids reflection and speeds up the load of the page.

Hopefully either Brian Lagunas or Dan Siegel will answer this one.

Can somebody clarify if compiled binding is supported in prism and how to do it or does it magically do it or do we need to manually set bindingcontext.

An answer would be greatly appreciated by anyone?

**updated with noddy sample**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="PrismCompiledBinding.Views.MainPage"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:models="clr-namespace:PrismCompiledBinding.Models">

        <!--x:DataType="ViewModel:MainPageViewModel"-->
        <!--mc:Ignorable="d"-->
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                SeparatorVisibility="None"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate  x:DataType="models:Monkey">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout
                                Padding="20,10,0,10"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Spacing="20"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                <Label
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using Prism.Navigation;
    using PrismCompiledBinding.Models;

    namespace PrismCompiledBinding.ViewModels
    {
        public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
                : base(navigationService)
            {
                Monkeys = GetMonkeys();
            }


            private ObservableCollection<Monkey> monkeys;

            public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys
            {
                get => monkeys;
                set => SetProperty(ref monkeys, value);
            }

            private ObservableCollection<Monkey> GetMonkeys()
            {
                ObservableCollection<Monkey> list=new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
                list.Add(new Monkey
                {
                    Name = "Baboon",
                    Location = "Africa & Asia",
                    Details =
                        "Baboons are African and Arabian Old World monkeys belonging to the genus Papio, part of the subfamily Cercopithecinae.",
                });
                list.Add(new Monkey
                {
                    Name = "Capuchin Monkey",
                    Location = "Central & South America",
                    Details =
                        "The capuchin monkeys are New World monkeys of the subfamily Cebinae. Prior to 2011, the subfamily contained only a single genus, Cebus.",
                });
                return list;
            }
        }
    }

       public class Monkey
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public string Details { get; set; }
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes *Compiled Bindings* works fine with *Prism*.

I specifically tested it using Prism version *7.2.0.1422* and Xamarin.Forms *4.2.0.848062*.

I followed [this tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/compiled-bindings-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: thanks for your reply. are you saying it just "works" and you did not not have to manually set the bindnigcontext

Comment: Yes I didn't need to change any Prism-related code such as BindingContext.

Comment: do you have a dummy project somewhere ?

Comment: Nope. I've used it on my own project. You can simply follow the tutorial link I provided and apply that to a Prism new project template.

Comment: In case you face any problems while applying it on your project feel free to come back and ask again.

Comment: I have updated with a noddy xample I have just build.I guess I do not need  <!--x:DataType="ViewModel:MainPageViewModel"-->
        <!--mc:Ignorable="d"-->  Correct? with those the app does not build  , Do I also need this  xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"?

Comment: `x:DataType` is necessary and by using it we in fact determine the binding context of where it is used. For a page it is usually a view model and for a list view's item it's a model. You already configured it correctly for your list view. And you need to do the same for page by adding a line similar to `"xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PrismCompiledBinding.ViewModels"` and then x:DataType="ViewModel:MainPageViewModel"`.

Comment: the line: `"xmlns:d="xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" and mc:Ignorable="d"` are not necessary for your purpose.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help for some reasons adding those gives me an error "undeclared xmlns prefix viewmodel" and that is why i removed it which makes no sense .Missing the obvious.. hence why I wanted a quick example that works to see what I miss

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, You want to binding in Prism.Form. If you want to use Prism.Forms, you need to install **Prism Template Pack**, go to **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates** select **Online** and search for **Prism Template Pack**. Locate the the extensions, click Download, and complete the installation firstly.

Then needing to do following thing:

```
 xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
```

The Prism library is referenced.

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

This view (MainPage.xaml) is wired to the view model (MainPageViewModel.cs) automatically via naming conventions allowing for databinding to the view model. So you don't need to bind BindContext.

I do one sample that you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/PrismApp

There are also two article that may help you:

https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html

https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-xamarin-forms-and-prism

Comment: Bu Thanks for your reply. I am already using the Prism template pack and here we are talking about "Compiled binding in prism"  I have no problem in using prism without compiled binding. Regarding the "AutowireViewModel" that is not necesssary at all and uses reflection as I am doing <MyView,MyViewModel> . Again This post is all about compiled binding.. many thanks

Comment: @Ted,I find one article about setting bindingcontext, it may be helpful to you:https://blog.nuits.jp/enable-intellisense-for-viewmodel-members-with-prism-for-xamarin-forms-2f274e7c6fb6